# Laravel - insert data into a table that contains id of other tables

Tags: sql, laravel, insert

[image]

i have a table in my database( table case ) that contains case type id which is a foreign key to the table (case_type). when users fill this table they dont know the case type id they only know the category of the case. so what i want to do is when users fill the case table they write the case type category and based on that it match the category with the case id since i have a separate table and submit that id in to the case table.
so far what i have tried :

from vue i send the category selected from a dropdown by the user to this controller function

```
  public function getIdOfCategoryByName(Request $request){
        $name = $request->input('name');
        $getidbyname=case_type::where('category',$name)->get('id');
        return $getidbyname;
    }
```

this is where i dont know how to insert the id that i got back to this function

```
public function createcase(){
       $request->validate([
           'title' => 'required',
           'description' => 'required',
           'caseTypeId' => 'required',
           'amountreceived' => 'required',
           'amoutneeded' =>'required',
           'uid' => 'required',
           'visible' => 'required',
           'image' => 'required',
           'cityId' => 'required'

       ]);
      waitingdonations::create($request->post());
       return response()->json([
           'message' => 'waiting donation successfull',
       ]); 
   }
```

if my  question is unclear please check this website https://towardsdatascience.com/sql-insert-values-with-joined-ids-from-another-table-83ff7f149296

Comment: You are complicating way more than it should. Just send the value of the dropdown (in this case `caseTypeId`) along with the form which will create the case. The `getIdOfCategoryByName()` is redundant and doesn't serve any purpose in this case. A simple `select` would suffice here.

Comment: so if i have a case type of id 1 and category education <option value="1">category:  education</option>. you suggest i do it this way?. in that case i have to manually input the id of the categories for the dropdown right? @itachi

Comment: Nononono, do you hardcode your categories or do you fetch it in the database ?

Comment: fetch it from the database @xenooooo

Comment: It means you can also fetch the id alongside the name

Comment: how do you render the value ?

Comment: okay so i can send the category table to my front with API, and then display it with something like this  @foreach($casetypes as casetype)
        <option value="{{$casetype->id}}">
            {{$casetype->category}}
        </option>
    endforeach                                                                                                                                       @xenooooo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249924/discussion-between-aliana-and-xenooooo).